# how to add arrays and examples in my Swagger UI using Swagger express?

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui

To sum it up, I basically am trying to make a swagger Ui based on this "tutorial" : https://github.com/fliptoo/swagger-express

Unfortunately, it doesn't describe at all how to add examples for the body and how to add arrays as well.

The code for the documentation I have right now is :

```
/**
* @swagger
* path: /animal/dogs
* operations: 
*   -  httpMethod: POST
*      summary: Add several dogs to the animal shelter
*      notes: Returns results of the post
*      responseClass: Shelter
*      nickname : shelterPostWithDogs
*      consumes: 
*        - application/json
*      parameters:
*        - name: body
*          schema: true
*          description: Dogs object that needs to be added
*          paramType: body
*          required: true
*          dataType: Dog
*/
```

And I have at the bottom :

```
/**
* @swagger
* models:
*  Dog:
*      id: Dog
*      properties:
*          dog_id:
*              required: true
*              type: int
*  Shelter:
*      id: Shelter
*      properties:
*          shelter_id:
*              type: int
*          location:
*              type: string                             
*/
```

Unfortunately, with this, I have this in my Model :

```
Dog {
    dog_id (int)
}
```

I would like instead to have this:

```
Dog {
    [
        { dog_id(int)}
    ]
}
```

What do I have to change to get this result?

Bonus : How do I add examples to my model? I would like something similar to this one : http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/addPet
Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it in swagger express

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to swagger-express but one thing I will suggest, you have to use type as "array" in models definition:

```
Dog:
   id: Dog
      properties:
          dog_id:
              required: true
              type: **array**
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks!